# Ruby: replace in string ampersand to backslash with ampersand

Tags: ruby

Simple question, but I can't find simple answer

I have a string

```rb
str = 'a&b'
```

I need to replace & to \&

```rb
str
>>> a\&b
```

In php I can do it like this

```php
str_replace('&', '\\&', $str); \\ >>> a\&b
```

But in ruby this not working

```rb
str.gsub('&', '\\&')
>>> a&b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
2.0.0-p0 :018 > "a&b".gsub('&', '\\\&')
 => "a\\&b"
2.0.0-p0 :019 > _.chars.to_a
 => ["a", "\\", "&", "b"]
2.0.0-p0 :023 > puts "a&b".gsub('&', '\\\&')
a\&b
```

Comment: I don't need two backslashes, I need one. Instead of a\\&b I need a\&b

Comment: This is not two backslashes. This is one backslash.

Answer (score 4):

A solution using a block:

```
> puts 'a&b'.gsub('&') { '\&' }
a\&b
```

In the block form, backreferences prefixed with `\` are not interpreted, as is the case in the replacement parameter of `gsub`.

In the block form, there are $n, $&... variables available instead.

In the form of gsub you are using, the double-backslash must be escaped with yet another backslash.

Comment: You have unneded block param. It will print unneded variable warning. God way is `'a&b'.gsub('&') { |_| '\&' }`, better way is `'a&b'.gsub('&') { '\&' }`, the best way is the one proposed by @DNNX: `'a&b'.gsub('&', '\\\&')`

Comment: yes, fixing the param. How is the other solution the "best" ? please detail your arguments :)

Comment: In your version there is block which must be called each time when there is `&` found. In the other solution there is no need to call other function. We got our replacement right there and we can replace each hit at instatnt in one C function (I don't remember that YARV store return values, even if it do so, block receive different argument each time when it run). So 'the best' soution simply is the fastest one.

Comment: While I don't think my solution is better, another fact must be also taken into account. The replacement string in the first form must be parsed to search for backreferences, and substitutions will occur, while in the block form, the returned string is used as-is. All in all, I'm not sure there are major speed advantages, but it is interesting to measure this empirically :)

Comment: IMHO parsing for backreference will still be faster (as can be done in pure C) than calling back and parsing Ruby code (as we know, Ruby isn't fastest language).

Comment: @Hauleth 8 years later : who cares if this solution is a bit slower than another one. At least it makes sense, and I don't need to remember that I need 3 backslashes...